# Running ASPX code to get an index of all files in a Document Library

Tags: aspx

I once was (in a previous century) an oldskool Classic ASP developer, never touched .Net

Can we execute code in an ASPX file in a Document Library like we did with ASP?

I would like to built an UL/LI list of files starting with string 'XYZ'

Could do it client side with REST, a server side solution might be better
(*never thought that would come from my mouth*)

Comment: Why not just use SharePoint Search abilities?

Comment: I can do any REST call, but creating server side has the advantage of not having to wait (milliseconds) to make a call. So I wonder if Inline Code (not .Net) can be used... In SP2007 it was disabled, and I never looked into it since then. wonder if anything has changed